# Cups failed, laptop won’t start

Tags: printing

I’m having issues with my laptop, it won’t start due to a failed cups scheduler. It just doesn’t want to let me in and it keeps showing that failure every few minutes on a black screen. I’m trying to run Ubuntu now from a usb maybe there’s a way I can fix the cups so I can start the lap top, and save some files I have in and reinstall Ubuntu, I’ve been having some major issues with it lately.

I’d be grateful if I can get an answer, been trying for 2 days to fix it.

```
[FAILED] failed to start cups scheduler
[Depend] dependency failed for make remote cups printers available locally
```

Comment: Have you tried recovery mode? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode Right after power-on press/hold shift to expose the grub menu > in the grub menu, pick advanced options for Ubuntu > pick recovery mode > pick 'drop to root shell' > follow the instructions, if any. From this shell prompt you can carry out whatever repair attempts.

Comment: Please edit your question and include *details* - exact error messages you receive, etc.

Comment: Honestly I haven’t tried recovery mode, I just panicked because of that failure message. I did manage to get into some kind of window which is asking for some login credentials  I never set up during the installation. Trying to run Ubuntu from the usb seemed like a good idea at the moment. 
The exact message I was getting was 
[FAILED]failed to start cups scheduler

Comment: Update: can’t get into recovery mode. Meanwhile, still getting the same error don’t know what to do about it